# How to use custom labels in Email templates?

Tags: email-template, customlabel

I want to use custom labels in the email template to display images stored in the documents.

I want to store the base URl and Ids in a label so that I can fix them on moving them to other sandboxes.

Comment: What is the type of your email template? Is it a VF template?

Comment: Only VF templates can have CL.

Comment: It is an HTML template.

Answer (score 8):

Use below syntax to get the custom label in the Email Template, Please remember to enclose the syntax with single quote(').

```
'{!$Label.LabelName}'
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is down-voted. Perhaps it didn't work in 2016? But it does work now. You can use {!$Label.LabelName} in text/html classic email templates in Winter 19

Comment: Was able to use the label without the single quote in the subject line. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: unable to use {!$Label.LabelName}' with or without quotes in body of classic email template

Comment: I can't get the label to work in the body of the email by itself. It does work in the subject and it does work in the URL of a link merge field. But whenever I use it by itself in the body the merge field gets replaced with blank text. I tried with and without the single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use VisualForce HTML template. Here's how to use it:

Suppose in the template, the Billing Address is written as follows:

```
<apex:variable var="billingAddress" value="Billing Address" />
```

To use the label change this to:

```
<apex:variable var="billingAddress" value="{!$Label.BillingAddress}"/>
```

As another example, you can change a literal value within the Visualforce markup like this:

```
<td>My Label</td>
```

To use a created label called MyLabel, instead of a literal, change this to:

```
<td>{!Label.MyLabel}</td>
```

And this should work fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format to use custom labels in the classic email templates.

```
{!$Label.put_your_label_api}
```

But to use images in the email you can create a formula field in which you can use this below formula and pass the url of image where it is publicly hosted.

```
IMAGE(image_url, alternate_text [, height, width])
```